# Quantos significados têm o verbo mexer em português europeu?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, verbos, expressões-idiomáticas, significado-em-contexto

Eu vi no YouTube que o verbo mexer tem muitos significados no português do Brasil, mas não sei se os portugueses falam assim também.

Aqui vou pôr os vídeos de referência:

1. https://youtu.be/ueHfJdgOJps
2. https://youtu.be/1rC0WuMSvpA

Comment: Acho que você deveria procurar na Priberam. https://dicionario.priberam.org/mexer Você conhece? E comparar com o Houaiss ou outro dicionário brasileiro. Geralmente, se pede aos participantes trazer alguma pesquisa ou esforço pessoal para as preguntas.

Comment: Secundo o comentário de Lambie acima. Por curiosidade chequei uns dicionários: 2 portugueses, [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mexer) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/mexer) que listam, ambos, 12 significados; e dois brasileiros, [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/mexer), que também lista 12, e [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mexer/), com 13. Essa análise superficial indicaria não haver grande diferença entre os 'mexeres' de pt-BR e pt-PT.

Comment: Obrigada pelas suas respostas!! Foram de muito ajuda para mim.